# How to make a surface in maya？

Tags: maya

I'd like to make some specific surfaces such as rotating surfaces, ruled surfaces，and canal surfaces, and export them as obj file. I try to do this by the software maya, How to do this?

Comment: Hello, StackOverflow is a programming-related Q&A site, your question appears to be off-topic as described in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question is unlikely to get any answer here. If your plan is to export your surfaces using a mel or python script, you question can be on-topic but you have to be precise on what you are willing to achieve in your question. If you want to export your surfaces to obj using Maya's UI, your question is off-topic. In the second case, I invite you to ask your question on more appropriate websites.

Comment: Some of the website I usualy use to find answers: [CGSociety forums](http://forums.cgsociety.org/), [Creative Cow forums](https://forums.creativecow.net/maya) or [Autodesk Maya forums](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya/ct-p/area-c2). A quick tip on your problem: Select the desired surfaces to export. Goto `File -> Export selection` (Click on the square) Set `File type` to obj. `Export selection`.